# How to use conditional relationship in API Resource?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created an API Resource:

```php
class OrderResource extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->Id,
            "photo" => ''
        ];
    }
}
```

In controller I get data from model `OrderModel` the put data into resource `OrderResource`:

```php
public function show($id)
{
        $order = OrderModel::with('OrderPhoto')->findOrFail(1);

        return new OrderResource($order);
}
```

So, I tried to use relation `OrderPhoto` in `OrderResource` like this:

```php
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->Id,
            "photo" => OrderPhotoResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('OrderPhoto')),
        ];
    }
```

But it does not work and gives this error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$map

I did `dd($this)` in resource and what I got:

[image]

**Class OrderPhoto:**

```php
class OrderPhoto extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also place the code of the `OrderPhotoResource` class?

Comment: Sure it is simple, posted

Comment: So, in line `"photo" => OrderPhotoResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('OrderPhoto'))` I try to get loaded relation data `OrderPhoto` and put to OrderPhotoResource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

Try this in your `OrderResource`:

```php
use OrderPhoto as OrderPhotoResource;

//

public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        "id" => $this->Id,
        "photo" => new OrderPhotoResource($this->whenLoaded('OrderPhoto')),
    ];
}
```

---

## Explanation

As you can see, you are already defining the `OrderPhoto` as a Resource Collection:

```php
class OrderPhoto extends ResourceCollection // <-- note the extended class
```

So in this case, you'll need to use this class **instanciating** it and pass in it the collection, instead of using the static method `collection`.

When you define a API Resource for a single object, like this:

```php
php artisan make:resource PostResource
```

you use it like below:

```php
$post = Post::find(1);

return new PostResource($post);
```

And if you want to use an **API Resource** to format a collection of resources instead of a single one, you need to do this:

```php
$posts = Post::all();

return PostResource::collection($posts); // <-- note the ::collection part
```

#### Controlling the metadata

If you want to have a total control of the returned metadata in the response, define a custom **API Resource Collection** class instead.

Generate the class as a collection (adding the 'Collection' at the end or using the flag `--collection`):

```php
php artisan make:resource PostResourceCollection
```

then, after customize it:

```php
$posts = Post::all();

return new PostResourceCollection($posts); // <-- instantiating the class
```

Comment: @OPV I'm just using the class name that you pasted as your `OrderPhotoResource` class in your last update, replace it with the correct class name

Comment: Man I did the same thing that you offered

Comment: But I tried to return `OrderPhotoResource` in another resource

Comment: @OPV in your posted question? Is not the same, you are using the static method: `ResourcePhoto::collection` but that class is alredy refined as a collection one so just instanciate it like shown.

Comment: Okay, I got it, will try now

Comment: In your offered answer I can not control output data for `OrderPhotoResource`, because it is array I mean: `public function toArray($request)
    { return ["photo" => $this->photo]; }`

Comment: It is still not clear cause I have array of data from relation

Comment: This is because the purpose of specific Collection classes is to handle the metadata returned in responses. If you want to customize every item you need to use a API Resource for single element and return it using the static method `collection`. Of course, you can merge this two classes to have a total control of the response.

Comment: @OPV check the [Resource Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources) part of the documentation to have a clear undestanding of this two classes and their purposes.

Comment: Okay in my case `photos` is collection, how to modify response for each item inside OrderPhotoResource

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183858/discussion-between-hck-and-opv).